# Some or all identity references could not be translated

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, access-rules

I want to set some access rules to a file. Now when i set the rule, the variable `name` contains the right username (like: domain\user).

```
string name = new SecurityIdentifier(rule.IdentityReference.Value).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
accessControl.AddAccessRule(rule);
```

But the next line throws a IdentityNotMappedException with the message:

> Some or all identity references could not be translated.

why I can translate in the first line the IdentityReference to a username, but the second line can't translate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I found this solution:

create the rule, and set the `identityReferences` to this: `new SecurityIdentifier(identity)`